# How To Execute an Integration Services (SSIS) Package from a SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

i am executing query like this on sql server 2008 R2

```
DECLARE @returncode int
EXEC @returncode = xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /f "C:\certs\SSIS Disposition\SSIS Disposition\SSIS Disposition\Package1.dtsx"'
```

and getting error

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
NULL
Started:  12:08:21 AM
Error: 2014-03-21 00:08:21.71
   Code: 0xC0016016
   Source:  
   Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that
 the correct key is available.
End Error
Progress: 2014-03-21 00:08:22.66
   Source: Data Flow Task 1 
   Validating: 0% complete
End Progress
Progress: 2014-03-21 00:08:22.69
   Source: Data Flow Task 1 
   Validating: 50% complete
End Progress
Error: 2014-03-21 00:08:23.05
   Code: 0xC0202009
   Source: Package1 Connection manager "DestinationConnectionOLEDB"
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'wm_bulk'.".
End Error
Error: 2014-03-21 00:08:23.07
   Code: 0xC020801C
   Source: Data Flow Task 1 Destination - ACQ_DailyFeedStaging [220]
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "DestinationConnectionOLEDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before thi
s with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
End Error
Error: 2014-03-21 00:08:23.07
   Code: 0xC0047017
   Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: component "Destination - ACQ_DailyFeedStaging" (220) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
End Error
Progress: 2014-03-21 00:08:23.07
   Source: Data Flow Task 1 
   Validating: 100% complete
End Progress
Error: 2014-03-21 00:08:23.07
   Code: 0xC004700C
   Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: One or more component failed validation.
End Error
Error: 2014-03-21 00:08:23.07
   Code: 0xC0024107
   Source: Data Flow Task 1 
   Description: There were errors during task validation.
End Error
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  12:08:21 AM
Finished: 12:08:23 AM
Elapsed:  1.544 seconds
NULL
```

Comment: Open the package in BIDS and report back on what the current ProtectionLevel is

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though the package has been saved with sensitive data protected, meaning that it can only be run by specified users.

To fix it, set the **PackageProtectionLevel** to **DontSaveSensitive** and then re-deploy the package to the server.

[image: Set the package Protection Level]

Comment: Or they need to create a stored credential that is authorized to decrypt the package or provide the password to decrypt the package. While I wholeheartedly support a package protection level of `DontSaveSensitive` as a standard, if they don't have configuration in place, this is going to cause additional work for them to configure package execution